# Convolution using QFT with 2 vectors

Tags: quantum-fourier-transform

I am doing an experiment in Qiskit - trying to mimic convolution of 2 vectors and getting the result of convolution using element-wise approach.

However, I as doing necessary steps the result I get is very different from actual result.
As I was searching internet, there was an research paper that quantum convolution is not possible.

Could someone in this sub could affirm this and I am wasting my time trying to create which is not possible?

The steps I taking for this in Qiskit:

1. Normalizing 2 same size vectors and create circuits for them.
2. Apply QFT for both circuits.
3. Combine them and perform controlled rotations with values.
4. Apply IQFT.
5. Measure result.